# How do I set an alert based on the HTML Text in android

Tags: android, html

currently I'm pulling text from a website using

```
public String getText(String uri) {
    HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);


    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        String response_str = client1.execute(request, responseHandler);
        return response_str;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";

    }
}
```

and I get a bunch of HTML code that is filtered with `Html.fromHtml()` which cleans up all the HTML text and leaves me with the dialog I want.

However this method cannot let me set the title of the alert dialog because it only comes out as one string and cannot differentiate between whats in the  parameters from the `<body></body>` parameters. It also doesn't filter out some comments such as

```
     <!--BODY{color:white; background-color:transparent;......
```

How can I delete the extra HTML text and separate the title portion from the main body of the text. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) string class.

> "This is the interface for text to which markup objects can be attached
>   and detached. Not all Spannable classes have mutable text; see
>   Editable for that."

Answer (score 0):

To parse HTML, use an [HTML-Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) as there are some out there.

In the case that you control the formating/content of that pulled/desired HTML-Page, you'll want to switch from HTML to something better suited for your needs like a simple XML-Language or JSON.

Comment: HTML is an XML language? Really? I thought they both were subsets of SGML, but (could) be exclusive, with XHTML being XML-specific HTML.

Comment: Jeah, you're right about that, thanks for correcting me. I edited that.

Comment: Oh geez. Wash the thought that HTML and XML are in any way alike, since they are not alike. The best chance that the OP has is that they could use a DOM parser, but an XML parser could (would?) end in tears.

Comment: I see that. However, XHTML should be parsable using an XML-Parser?

Comment: IF it parses, which means very strict rules in how the markup is emitted. It's tricky in the best of circumstances.

Comment: XHTML is great to validate markup against, but in the real world, it's just not useful.

Comment: Also, it wasn't designed to do what the OP is trying to do. So changing to XML or JSON might be the best solution (if possible).

Comment: Ok. Using regular expressions for HTML is also [consider toxic](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Not deadly, but possibly deleterious. Depending...

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I am familiar with working with JSON, can you show me how to take an HTML string and put the respective values into its keys e.g JSON:("Body,"This is the body")==HTML:<Body>This is the Body</Body>

Comment: What I meant was that you only send those informations you need and present them using JSON. So you don't have all the HTML-Stuff, just the JSON-String. Of course this only works if you control what is presented by the server.